# Forecasting the best current estimate based on univariate low-frequency data

Tags: python, r, forecasting, arima, kalman-filter

Suppose I observe data annually and I need to derive a best current estimate based on the univariate historical observations in the time series only.

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-12-31 | ABC | 3150000 |
| 2006-12-31 | ABC | 5970000 |
| 2007-12-31 | ABC | 6640000 |
| 2008-12-31 | ABC | 6390000 |
| 2009-12-31 | ABC | 7130000 |
| 2010-12-31 | ABC | 7270000 |
| 2011-12-31 | ABC | 7030000 |
| 2012-12-31 | ABC | 7360000 |
| 2013-12-31 | ABC | 7470000 |
| 2014-12-31 | ABC | 7810000 |
| 2015-12-31 | ABC | 8690000 |
| 2016-12-31 | ABC | 8910000 |
| 2017-12-31 | ABC | 2820000 |
| 2018-12-31 | ABC | 4380000 |
| 2019-12-31 | ABC | 2720000 |
| 2020-12-31 | ABC | 2480000 |
| **2021-03-31** | ABC | **w** |
| **2021-06-30** | ABC | **x** |
| **2021-09-30** | ABC | **y** |
| **2021-12-31** | ABC | **z** |

My thinking was to fit an ARIMA model and then use a Kalman filter on the state-space representation of the ARIMA model to derive a best estimate of the next observation.

1. Assume I don't want to just forecast the next annual data point, but derive quarterly estimates (**w**, **x**, **y**, **z**) where my estimate becomes more uncertain the further I move away from the last true observation. Is there a way of tackling this problem and how would you go about it?
2. How would I integrate the uncertainty around the forecast into the estimate the further I move away from the last true observation?
3. Is ARIMA + KF the most appropriate way of tackling this or can you think of other approaches to the problem?

I am indifferent to solving this issue in R or Python.

Thank you for sharing your ideas.

Here is my dataset:

```
structure(list(date = c("2005-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2007-12-31", 
"2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", "2012-12-31", 
"2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
"2018-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2020-12-31", "2021-03-31", "2021-06-30", 
"2021-09-30", "2021-12-31"), id = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
"ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
"ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC"), value = c("3150000", 
"5970000", "6640000", "6390000", "7130000", "7270000", "7030000", 
"7360000", "7470000", "7810000", "8690000", "8910000", "2820000", 
"4380000", "2720000", "2480000", "w", "x", "y", "z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking at Rob Hyndman's book on this topic, as he addresses ARIMA and many other choices for forecasting in great detail and provides super practical code and advice too: https://otexts.com/fpp2/ -

To your question, the choice of the model selection if of course dependent on the assumptions you're willing to take on. e.g., depending on the form of the errors, you will have a unique ARIMA model of some order. And to get something believable, you should probably make sure the data are pre-whitened, all of which feels pretty artificial in my opinion. Certainly just an opinion; no judgement intended.

But as such, I tend to like non-ARIMA-style models like many in Hyndman's text, such as prophet, neural nets, exponential smoothing, etc. which are often more agnostic about error distribution, and more so focus on the contours of the time series, and use that to inform forecasts. Either way, take a look at a simple example in R in line with what I've said. I hope it's helpful as a start.

```
# your data (slightly updated)
data <- structure(list(
  date = c(
  "2005-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2007-12-31",
  "2008-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", 
  "2011-12-31", "2012-12-31", "2013-12-31", 
  "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", 
  "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2019-12-31", 
  "2020-12-31"), 
  value = c(
    "3150000", "5970000", "6640000", "6390000", 
    "7130000", "7270000", "7030000", "7360000", 
    "7470000", "7810000", "8690000", "8910000", 
    "2820000", "4380000", "2720000", "2480000")), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -16L))

# load some libs
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(fable)
library(fable.prophet)
library(tsibble)

data_ts <- data %>% 
  mutate(date = yearmonth(date),
         value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  as_tsibble()

# take a look at the ts, if desired
data_ts %>%
  autoplot(value) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(title = "Values Overtime",
       x = "Date",
       y = "Value")

# fit models
fit <- data_ts %>%
  model(
    `Naïve` = NAIVE(value), # include a (usually) good, simple model for comparison
    ARIMA = ARIMA(value),
    ETS = ETS(value),
    NNETAR = NNETAR(value)
  )

# generate 2 year forecasts 
forecast <- fit %>%
    forecast(h = 2) # could be "2 years" if desired

# take a look; will generate a forecast for each year/h level
forecast 

OUTPUT:
> forecast 
# A fable: 8 x 4 [12M]
# Key:     .model [4]
  .model     date               value    .mean
  <chr>     <mth>              <dist>    <dbl>
1 Naïve  2021 Dec N(2480000, 3.5e+12) 2480000 
2 Naïve  2022 Dec   N(2480000, 7e+12) 2480000 
3 ARIMA  2021 Dec N(3529357, 3.3e+12) 3529357.
4 ARIMA  2022 Dec N(4204751, 4.7e+12) 4204751.
5 ETS    2021 Dec N(2705245, 6.4e+11) 2705245.
6 ETS    2022 Dec N(2705245, 9.8e+11) 2705245.
7 NNETAR 2021 Dec        sample[5000] 3889162.
8 NNETAR 2022 Dec        sample[5000] 4335662.
```

Comment: Hi @pdw5. Thank you very much for your reply and useful example. This is a nice addition to what I have been toying around with over the past week. I note that the forecast here is still a yearly and simply 2 years out. I am looking to forecast more frequently intra-year and accounting for the fact that my estimate becomes more uncertain the further I move away from the last yearly observation. Is this something you have come across in the past?

Comment: Hi @env11, glad that help a little. To your question about narrower time intervals (than a year in this case), there are a number of feature engineering steps you could take to decompose the time series how you'd like. E.g., take a look at the timetk package in r: https://business-science.github.io/timetk/articles/TK03_Forecasting_Using_Time_Series_Signature.html. And re: uncertainty, I'd calculate error's at each time point, and plotting accordingly. Take a look here: https://otexts.com/fpp2/weekly.html. I hope this helps!